# How to select commands based on file syntax in Sublime Text

Tags: syntax, sublimetext3, key-bindings, prettify, jscs

*I spent way too much time working out exactly how to override a particular code formatting tool in favor of another one when editing JavaScript, but leaving the other one in place for formatting HTML and CSS.*

*I didn't find any complete instructions here on SO or in other places, so I decided to post the Q&A here.*

### Problem:

HTMLPrettify listens to a specific key binding (super-shift-h) and then runs a Prettify script variant depending on file syntax.  It handles HTML, CSS, JS, and JSON.

**I wanted JSCS**

I found JSCS and liked that it easily matched and handled not only the basics, but also had tons of options for coding **style**.

To me the coolest thing about it is that the user can simply select a well known JS style guide like airbnb or jquery and JSCS will match the style it formats code in to that style.

Anyway, I wanted to use that instead.  But I wanted to keep HTMLPrettify for HTML and CSS and couldn't find a way to choose one for JS and JSON, but the other for HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

HTMLPrettify captures the key binding in it's own config file, which gets loaded *after* and therefore overrides the default and user key bindings.

JSCS defaults to the same key binding as HTMLPrettify, so it ends up being a fight for who gets called.

To resolve this, it's necessary to remove the key binding from HTMLPrettify in it's settings, and then add some custom user key bindings that use a conditional context looking at the syntax type.

---

**Change the first option in the HTMLPrettify settings to:**

```
[{
  "keys": [""],
  "command": "htmlprettify"
},
```

**Then add the following to your User Key Bindings file in SublimeText:**

```
[
  { 
    "keys": ["super+shift+h"], 
    "command": "format_javascript",
    "context": [
      { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.js" },
      { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.json" },
    ]
  },
  { 
    "keys": ["super+shift+h"], 
    "command": "htmlprettify",
    "context": [
      { "key": "selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "source.js" },
      { "key": "selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "source.json" },
    ]
  }
]
```

Note that the "not_equal"  parts are necessary because Sublime Text (at least on OSX) seems to have a bug where it's necessary to explicitly exclude any other matches or it will simple (in this case) run JSCS against everything.

I haven't tested it, but I imagine that if you had other formatters you wanted to include, you could use the "equal" pattern for each of them, matching to the source type, and then use the "not_equal" pattern to match to an empty command.

**Personal Note**

Code formatting is a very common function. Specific engines for formatting specific syntaxes should be decoupled from the key-binding so that a single key binding could be used for all "format" commands and the syntax would determine which engine to use based in which one the user assigned.

This likely could be made into a SublimeText plugin fairly easily.  Or, by convention plugin developers could simply be careful to add context to their key bindings and leave the binding "namespace" open for other syntaxes.